# What does the colon do in this line of code?

Tags: java, arrays, playing-cards

I found this code online that helps me with my homework, but I don't understand what it means. What I want to do is create a method called "handScore" that adds together the ranks of a card array. The value of each card is basically what their rank is, However, if the rank of the card is a jack, queen, or king, the value will simply be 10 and ace has a value of 1.

This is the code I found

```
public static int handScore (Cards[] cards){
    int handTotal = 0; 
    for(Cards c : cards) {  
        int cardTotal = c.rank;  

        if(cardTotal > 10){ 
            cardTotal = 10; 
        } 
        handTotal += cardTotal; 
    }
    return handTotal;
}
```

My main confusion is about the colon in line 3, what does that do?

Comment: It is part of the **Java syntax** and means *"for each `c` in `cards`"*. On the right side you can write everything which is of type `Iterable`. The syntax is equivalent to fetching an `Iterator` by `cards.iterator()` and then doing `while(iter.hasNext()) { Cards c = iter.next(); ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate it as "For each `Cards` object in `cards` array do the following actions {...}"